# Merging Dataframes with Arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I hope you can offer some guidance - I'm writing a script using the Pandas library in Python v2.7.

One part of the script merges two data frames - one for revenue, and the other for performance data.  These DFs both have daily entries, and are linked by an ID column.

Performance Dataframe:

```
     RevID         Date       PartnerName        Performance        Revenue
     1,2           1/2/2015   Johndoe            0.02               0.00
     1             2/2/2015   Johndoe            0.12               0.00
     4             3/2/2015   Johndoe            0.10               0.00
```

*please note the '1,2' in the above row is referring to two IDs that need added together*

Revenue Dataframe:

```
     RevID     Date      Revenue
     1         1/2/2015  24000.00
     2         1/2/2015  25000.00
     1         2/2/2015  10000.00
     4         3/2/2015  94000.00
```

My question is, how can I perform a merge on these two rows taking into account that sometimes there will be a comma separated value (like an array) in the Performance DF that needs to have find the two corresponding revenue rows from the Revenue DF together - and the date.

For example, how would I approach this issue so that ultimately the table reads:

```
     RevID         Date       PartnerName        Performance        Revenue
     1,2           1/2/2015   Johndoe            0.02               49000.00
     1             2/2/2015   Johndoe            0.12               10000.00
     4             3/2/2015   Johndoe            0.10               94000.00
```

Note that the revenue in the first row has been added together with the values of RevID 1 and 2.
At this point, any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just dupe this data, then the issue with the comma goes away:

```
In [11]: res = pd.concat([df.iloc[i] for val, i in g.groups.items() for v in val.split(',')], ignore_index=True)

In [12]: res['RevID'] = sum([val.split(',') for val in g.groups], [])
```

and ensure the RevIDs are numeric rather than strings:

```
In [13]: res['RevID'] = res['RevID'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
  RevID      Date PartnerName  Performance  Revenue
0     1  2/2/2015     Johndoe         0.12        0
1     1  1/2/2015     Johndoe         0.02        0
2     2  1/2/2015     Johndoe         0.02        0
3     4  3/2/2015     Johndoe         0.10        0
```

That way you can merge and you're basically there:

```
In [21]: res.merge(df2, on=['RevID', 'Date'])
Out[21]:
   RevID      Date PartnerName  Performance  Revenue_x  Revenue_y
0      1  2/2/2015     Johndoe         0.12          0      10000
1      1  1/2/2015     Johndoe         0.02          0      24000
2      2  1/2/2015     Johndoe         0.02          0      25000
3      4  3/2/2015     Johndoe         0.10          0      94000
```

Note: you may want to remove the 0 Revenue column before merging (then you won't need to specify `on`).

*If you want to reference to an orignal ID (something unique) then you could groupby that and sum the Revenue, to get the frame you desired...*

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to avoid the suffix for the Revenue Column?  Ie:  If there is already a column there, with either a 0 or another number, to just sum the new revenue onto it, and not duplicate the col?

Comment: @JonathanKennedy I'm not sure actually, will have a think on it, would make a great question (post here if you write it - I'd upvote!)

Comment: Sure - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479701/avoiding-a-suffixed-column-upon-merge-instead-overwrite-any-existing-data